# Align table inside TD

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to get the rows in my table that resides in a TD to line up with the parent rows but the alignment is killing me.

Take a look here: http://teewebco.com/test.html

Here is mockup graphically of what it will look like

http://teewebco.com/images/main-copy.png

The reason for the table inside the TD is that can add new items and have it stretch automatically while keeping everything aligned..at least in theory.

Would there be a better way to do this possible?

Thanks

Comment: TeeWebCo is a full service company bringing world class websites within reach to your organization.

Comment: @Cadoo - absolutely priceless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS ... see http://jeffhowden.com/code/css/forms/

Comment: This is to style a form and not a grid. Any info you like on CSS grids?